# Coredata fetch not returning result just written to store

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Scenario:

I am on IOS using Magical record configured to operate against a SQLite database.  By default, MR configures coredata to serialize all writes back to the parent context on the main thread.

The pattern I use is that when I am not on the main thread I create a separate NSManagedObjectContext for coredata operations using something like MagicalRecord:MR_saveWithBlockAndWait.  Magical record creates the context, hooks it up to the parent context, performs whatever operations you specify in the callback block and finally saves.  Importantly, the save is supposed to be committed before the operation finishes.

When I am done working on the background thread I usually notify the UI that something has happened; e.g: something is downloaded/uploaded/changed.

On the UI thread I then create a new fetch request using the default context on the main thread.  The problem is that occasionally coredata doesn't find the new object I just committed previously.  The problem manifests itself in subtle race conditions where if the UI thread is slightly slow due to animations or whatever everything works fine - but sometimes it doesn't find the new object.

From what I have read fetch requests are always supposed to go to the disk.  There is also a staleness property on the MOC but it sounds like that is only regarding the cache and is bypassed if you do a fetch request.

Has anyone encountered similar issues and have any insights? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If you save changes on a background managed object context, but your UI context has already loaded that object, the UI context may just give you data from its cache instead of from the store file.

The usual approach to using multiple contexts is:

1. Observe `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` so that you'll know when the background context saves changes.
2. In your handler for this notification, call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on the UI context, so that it will update itself with changes from the other context.

You probably want to set the `mergePolicy` on your UI context, because the default is to just give up if there are any conflicting changes.

This applies to any multiple context scenario where each context needs to be updated with changes saved by a different context.

Comment: Sure, and I think that would make sense if I told core data to save and and wanted an alert when the write had flushed.  HOwever, my read of the MR code is that when you call MR_savewithBlockAndWait... it actually waits until the write has completed.

Comment: You're missing the point. The need to merge changes has absolutely nothing to do with whether the save has completed. It has to do with the managed object context using cached data, and your need to tell it that some of that data has changed.

Comment: and there is no way to just tell coredata to read from Sqlite and bypass its caches?  The problem is this: because a coredata object is inserted/updated/deleted doesn't tell you *what* the user intended.  That's why we have higher level messaging.  It sounds like I would need to drop a message on the UI thread that says "the next merge change is because a user changed the image color" and THEN wait for the merge notification.  This seems like it is ripe for a race condition.

Comment: There's also the `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` method. Call that for each object you want to refresh, with `NO` for the second argument, and then re-fetch the object. This is generally a lot more work, but it's possible.